# Python PyQt4 closing the application

Tags: python, dialog, qt4, python-2.7, pyqt4

I'm wondering, what is the best or the prefered way to close a dialog. Let's say I have my main window, settings and help window opened. The user decides to exit the main window, so how can I intercept the signal and what is the best way to close the windows that are opened?

Is the use of `dialogMain.close()` good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `closeEvent` method:

```
class YourApplication(QMainWindow):
  # ...

  def closeEvent(self, event):
    if condition:
      if QMessageBox.question(self, 'Your Application', 'Are you sure you want to exit?', QMessageBox.Yes, QMessageBox.No) == QMessageBox.Yes:
        # Do anything before the application closes

        event.accept()
      else:
        event.ignore()
```